# How to detect sleep in Mac

Tags: java, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

My Time-tracking application gets into hibernate-mode when the Mac it runs on gets into sleep mode (Forced sleep or by its own), this time goes untracked. The application needs to input this time as inert, is there any way to find that the Mac has gone to sleep and if it has woke-up.
And btw my app runs in Java.

Comment: I've never used this API, but you can try out [`java.awt.desktop.SystemSleepListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/desktop/SystemSleepListener.html) (added in Java 9).

Comment: Thank you for answering but I need to know If I can use Cocoa (Listing 1) and I/O Kit (Listing 3, Listing 4) for receiving sleep and wake notifications. => https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1340/_index.html                                       This link keeps coming up often in the related stackoverflow codes by the mentioned code has no beginnig or end and I have no idea on how to integrate it with my coide. Can you help me with this.

Comment: But you're using Java. Why not try to use the cross-platform API it provides? For all I know, it uses what you're talking about under-the-hood when executing on a Mac.

Comment: To answer your comment about using the Cocoa API: it should be possible to use it from Java ... but you are going to take the time read / learn about calling native code from your Mac Java application; e.g. Google for "calling Cocoa from Java" ... and watch out for out-of-date advice!!   (Mine would be to follow Slaw's suggestion above ...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/74601069/150978